# CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX()) error after uploading to domain

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

After uploading the file to a domain, this code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(StudentNumber, "-", -1) AS INT)
    FROM Students
    WHERE StudentNumber
    LIKE :year
    ORDER BY StudentNumber DESC
    LIMIT 1
');
$stmt->execute(['year'=>'S'.$currentYear.'-%']);
```

produces this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)
>                       FROM Students
>                       WHERE StudentNumber
>                       LIKE 'S19-%'
>                       ORDER BY' at line 1

The weird thing is, this exact code works normally in localhost. I tried searching if there are conflicts in using `CAST()` or `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in an online domain, but there seems to be none.

What is/are the possible cause/s for the error?

Comment: perhaps dif db servers? E.g. mariadb vs mysql?

Comment: @treyBake I don't think so, my host in the connection connects to mysql

Comment: hmm.. have you tried pasting the code directly into an MYSQL CLI (changing passed params to hard-values)?

Comment: @treyBake Also encountered the error in the mysql CLI online, but it is okay in the localhost

Comment: difference in mysql versions?

Comment: @treyBake They're different, and it seems `INT` must be changed to `UNSIGNED` for it to work, although I'm not sure why `INT` still worked in localhost

Comment: huh, maybe some subversion got stricter then :S at least you found the issue? xD

Comment: @treyBake Yeah, wanna make it an answer?

Comment: Nah - you found the solution, don't wanna steal rep - you go ahead :)